# How to move Ubuntu 12.04 launcher to the right?

Tags: 12.04, launcher

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04, and the launcher is on the left side of my monitor. This is great, except I'm using a dual screen setup and my main monitor is the one of the right, so when I select my main monitor as the one where launcher resides in, it's residing in the middle of my extended desktop, causing problems when I try to mouse between screens.

How do I place the launcher on the right side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of the operations in Ubuntu are by default. Hence, no one can change those. The placement of the launcher on the left side is by default. You cannot change it

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like they didn't think it through very well for people in my situation...

Comment: you can end up installing other system settings apps from software centre